# Stack Overflow quality requirements

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

Why did the following message appear when I tried to answer to a question:

> Please fix the following:
>
> Answer does not meet our quality requirements.

The answer was:

> I suggest you to set the image programmatically. I had the same problem with the color.

Comment: You need to post some more information, like the answer you wanted to post but couldn't. The system is saying it's not a good answer, but we can't say why if we can't see it.

Comment: How the system can undestand if my answer is good or not? A short answer doesn't mean a bad answer. Probably i can't see what is the problem because I'm using the stackoverflow application.

Comment: No idea how it can understand whether your answer is good or not, but if the answer was literally just what you now quoted, the system actually got it right.

Comment: Tha problem was that the app doesn't indent the code well. Using the browser it works perfetcly. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no code in the answer text that you posted above, but I assume you were talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399965/2057919) that you posted, which I am quoting here:

> I suggest you to set the color or the image programmatically. You can use:
>
> ```
>   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
>   button.setImageSource(R.drawable.image);
> ```

A couple of things to know:

1. The app *does* allow you to indent code, and it works just fine. You just need to indent manually or use the `{}` button in the formatting menu.
2. That answer is not a very good answer even with the proper formatting. It doesn't explain *why* or *how* it answers the question. Without the formatting, it would be a very bad answer, and the system was right to block it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice